# Same version of swift package in all local packages

Tags: ios, swift, package, swift-package-manager

I'm organizing my code using local swift packages, but many of them are using the same framework (Swinject in my case). So, almost all of my packages contain the same line:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "Swinject", url: "https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject.git", from: "2.7.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: ["Swinject"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

If I wanted to change the version of this package, I would need to change the dependency descriptions in all local packages. Is it possible to declare this dependency once and then use it from all packages?

Comment: `Package.swift` is just a swift file, so you could declare a global constant or static member of a struct, say, `PackageVersions` `static let swinjectVersion = "2.7.0"` and then just use that constant `from: PackageVersions.swinjectVersion`

Comment: It sounds like it may make more sense for you to have one package with multiple library products — depends on your situation, of course, but might be worth investigating

Comment: @Paulw11 but `Package.swift` doesn't compile, so how do I see this `struct` in another `Package.swift` file? Or am I missing something?